# how to convert Float64 to NSString in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, floating-point

How to convert `Float64` to `NSString` in objective-c?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%lf", number];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%lf", number];
```

Edit:

The difference is that you need to `release` the `str` variable in this case when you are done with it. We use `init` method to initialize class variables so that they can be accessible across the class and then release them in `dealloc`.

Comment: what are the consequences of using the above approaches? How do we decide when to use what?

Comment: They're the same, except that if you +alloc the string yourself, you'll also have to -release it at some point. For that reason, +stringWithFormat: is slightly more convenient if you don't plan on keeping the string around.